# What is the best way to add multiple products to the cart at a time in Hybris?

Tags: java, product, cart, sap-commerce-cloud

In my case, I have to add some related products to the cart at a time.My scenario is as the following:

1) Assume we have a product and assume its code is X-1

2) Assume we have another product which has code called X-2 and X-2 is like a complementary of X-1.

3) X-2 can be sold on its own but if we add X-1 to the cart in order to sell it, X-2 has to be added to the cart at the same time and price of X-2 has to be 0 in the cart since price of X-2 is included in the price of X-1.

Can you suggest any best practice for my scenario in Hybris-B2C accelerator?

Answer (score 2):

As you said in a comment, you don't want to use promotion here. So I hope, you already done some modeling to maintain parent-child products(let say package deal).

Now, while adding/removing to/from the cart, Identify package deal product(X-1) and with help of addTocart and updateCart hooks you can add or remove its child product(X-2) to the cart. Add child product as free gift(giveAway) product so you don't have to bother about calculation service.

To add and remove child product, you can implement below intefaces respectively and add your beans to hooks list.

`CommerceAddToCartMethodHook > afterAddToCart`

`CommerceUpdateCartEntryHook > afterUpdateCartEntry`

Add your bean to existing hooks(commerceAddToCartMethodHooks,commerceUpdateCartEntryHooks) like

```
     <bean id="myCommerceAddToCartMethodHooksList" depends-on="commerceAddToCartMethodHooks" parent="listMergeDirective" >
        <property name="add" ref="myBeanForAddtoCartHook" />
    </bean>
```

---

I had near a similar requirement(a package deal). Where we maintain package deals in ERP and push the same to Hybris. We only show all child products(X-2) information on parent product's(X-1) PDP. While adding it to the cart we only add parent product and send the order to ERP rest of thing is handed in ERP.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the promotion options for achieving this.AcceleratorProductBOGOFPromotion is the best option I can suggest.From backoffice you can choose marketing -> promotions -> Buy X get Y

Comment: Our customer does not want to take this scenario as a promotion since there are extra works in ERP for the customer.